# Observer update() method not being called

Tags: java, methods, observable, notify

in my Observable class I have 4 methods which use setChanged() and notifyObservers(), but the update() method in the Observer class is not running.

This is the update method:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    model = (Model) o;
    System.out.println("updated");

    if (!( Integer.parseInt(fromDropDownMenu.getSelectedItem().toString()) >= Integer.parseInt(toDropDownMenu.getSelectedItem().toString()) )){
        switch (model.getMethodNumber()){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("LEFT HAS BEEN PRESSED");
            if (currentCenterPanelIndex == 0){
                System.out.println("Can't go left.");
            } else {
                currentCenterPanel = listOfPanels[currentCenterPanelIndex--];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("RIGHT HAS BEEN PRESSED");
            if (currentCenterPanelIndex == 3){
                System.out.println("Can't go right.");
            } else {
                currentCenterPanel = listOfPanels[currentCenterPanelIndex++];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This is in the Observable class:

```
private int methodNum;

public void comboBoxUpdate(){
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void setMethodNum(int x){
    this.methodNum = x;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public int getMethodNumber(){
    return this.methodNum;
}

public void moveLeft(){
    System.out.println("LEFT");
    setMethodNum(1);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public void moveRight(){
    System.out.println("RIGHT");
    setMethodNum(2);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

Comment: You have to call `setChanged()` within your `update` method.

Comment: It says "The method setChanged() from the type Observable is not visible" when I do this.

Comment: *It says "The method setChanged() from the type Observable is not visible"* Then what is the base class of which you override the `update` method ?

Comment: the Observer class

Comment: Then `setChanged()` it is visible from within the update method. where did you try to put it?

Comment: in the update method

Comment: If you call `setChanged()` within your `update()` method of your extension of `Observable` it would be visible. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this problem.

Comment: update() is not in Observable, it's in Observer